# Combination Coutdown Date & List Button Filter Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a hero. I've combined two pieces of pure JS code - list filter & countdown - to form that which can be seen in full the Fiddle. However I'm well and truly stumped regarding what needs to be tweaked to have it behave in to meet my desired criteria below (this will be due to the fact that my knowledge on the matter is very limited, more than that it simply can't be done!)

1) Instead of search box and sort buttons, have buttons which when pressed activate pre-set filter. For example if we assume 4 buttons, 3 of these would be "Earth" "Mars" and "Saturn". Using the example from the Fiddle, when the "Earth" button is clicked this would return the two results with "Earth" in them, "Earth dies in: 157Days, 7Hours" and "Earth dies in: 126Days, 6Hours". The "Saturn" and "Mars" buttons would behave in the same way returning "Saturn dies in: Already Extinct!" and "Mars dies in: Already Extinct!" respectively.

2) Have a fourth button which instead of filtering for that term, excludes that term. This button for example could be called "Not Extinct", which would exclude those with the word "extinct" within the "enddate" span. This is where I've had no joy as even in it's current state content contained within the enddate span is not being found by the filter. I know if I didn't have the countdown it would work, but it's vital this remains.

3) To be able to have any combination of multiple buttons pressed/active at the same time. For example if you wanted to have both the "Earth" and "Not Extinct" pressed at the same time (or any combination).

To anyone who has read this thanks for taking the time, I tried to be as clear as possible which meant it's rather wordy so you've done well to get through it all. If you have a solution I'd be over the moon (keeping the space theme going) as I really need help! If there is anything that is unclear, let me know and I'll do my best to elaborate.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f484126/0uzo3ksy/3/)

```
<div id="users">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
<button class="sort" data-sort="name">Sort by name</button>
<button class="sort" data-sort="enddate">Sort by year</button>
<ul class="list">
<li>
<div>
<span class="name">Earth</span>dies in: <span class="enddate" data-countdown="November 20, 2015"></span>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div>
<span class="name">Mars</span> 
dies in: <span class="enddate" data-countdown="January 20, 2015"></span>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div>
<span class="name">Saturn</span> dies in: <span class="enddate" data-countdown="May 25, 2015"></span>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div>
 <span class="name">Earth</span> 
dies in: <span class="enddate" data-countdown="October 20, 2015"></span>
</div>
C</li>


Earth dies in: 157Days, 7Hours
Mars dies in: Already Extinct!
Saturn dies in: Already Extinct!
Earth dies in: 126Days, 6Hours
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your code using JQuery. I tried my best to stick to the same structure you have but I changed the buttons to checkboxes just because it makes the user experience a little better when multiple filters are selected. Here's my example

**EDITED**

I updated the example to use buttons. I added bootstrap for the css of the buttons, but you can use whatever css you want. As a reference I created a jsfiddle with the checkboxes here http://jsfiddle.net/vfaller/haotj66y/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  updatePlanetLifespan();
});

setInterval(function() {
  updatePlanetLifespan();
}, 1000);

function updatePlanetLifespan() {
  $('.enddate').each(function() {
    var cd = new Date();
    var current_date = cd.getTime();
    var dt = $(this).attr('data-countdown');
    var seconds_left = (new Date(dt + " 23:59").getTime() - current_date) / 1000;
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400, 10);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600, 10);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60, 10);
    if (seconds < -0) $(this).text('Already Extinct!');
    else if (hours < -0) $(this).text('Already Extinct!');
    else if (days < -0) $(this).text('Already Extinct!');
    else if (days < 1) $(this).text('Final day of Existence!');
    else if (days < 2) $(this).text('One More Day Until The End!');
    else $(this).text(days + ' Days, ' + hours + ' Hours ');
  });
}

var showEarth = false;
var showMars = false;
var showSaturn = false;
var dontShowExtinct = false;

function filterPlanet() {

  $('li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).show();
    var countdown = $(this).find('.enddate').text();

    if (countdown.indexOf('Extinct') > -1 && dontShowExtinct) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

  if (showEarth || showMars || showSaturn) {
    $('li').each(function(index) {
      var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
      var countdown = $(this).find('.enddate').text();

      if ((name === 'Earth' && !showEarth) || (name === 'Mars' && !showMars) || (name === 'Saturn' && !showSaturn)) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  }
}

$('#btnEarth').click(function() {
  if (showEarth) {
    showEarth = false;
    $(this).removeClass('btn-warning');
  } else {
    showEarth = true;
    $(this).addClass('btn-warning');
  }
  filterPlanet();

});

$('#btnMars').click(function() {
  if (showMars) {
    showMars = false;
    $(this).removeClass('btn-warning');
  } else {
    showMars = true;
    $(this).addClass('btn-warning');
  }
  filterPlanet();
});

$('#btnSaturn').click(function() {
  if (showSaturn) {
    showSaturn = false;
    $(this).removeClass('btn-warning');
  } else {
    showSaturn = true;
    $(this).addClass('btn-warning');
  }
  filterPlanet();
});

$('#btnNotExtinct').click(function() {
  if (dontShowExtinct) {
    dontShowExtinct = false;
    $(this).removeClass('btn-warning');
  } else {
    dontShowExtinct = true;
    $(this).addClass('btn-warning');
  }
  filterPlanet();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="users">
  <button id="btnEarth" class="btn">Earth</button>
  <button id="btnMars" class="btn">Mars</button>
  <button id="btnSaturn" class="btn">Saturn</button>
  <button id="btnNotExtinct" class="btn">Not Extinct</button>
  <br/>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <div> <span class="name">Earth</span> dies in: <span class="enddate" data-countdown="November 20, 2015"></span>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div> <span class="name">Mars</span> dies in: <span class="enddate" data-countdown="January 20, 2015"></span>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div> <span class="name">Saturn</span> dies in: <span class="enddate" data-countdown="May 25, 2015"></span>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div> <span class="name">Earth</span> dies in: <span class="enddate" data-countdown="October 20, 2015"></span>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! :) Out of interest are you able to create this with the buttons instead of checkboxes? I can use CSS to change the color of those selected for user the user experience.